# how to only include bibliography once

Tags: org-export, org-ref

How can I export these 2 files individually, but only include the bibliography **once** in the resulting `b.pdf`?

As shown, I get two copies of the References section in the `b.pdf` file.

I'm not sure if this is an `org-mode` only question, or if `org-ref` has the answer, so I
included both tags.

a.org

```
cite:something

bibliographystyle:unsrt
bibliography:stuff.bib
```

b.org

```
#+INCLUDE: "a.org"
cite:anotherthing

bibliographystyle:unsrt
bibliography:stuff.bib
```

Comment: Why are you adding the bibliography to `a.org`? Why not just  add it to `b.org` since that is the master file?

Comment: I want to export `a`. I also want to export `b`, which happens to include `a`.
Basically, when exporting `b`, I wish to "include all but the last 2 lines of a".

Comment: Delete the bibliography stuff from `a.org`, `b.org`; create `A.org` that includes `a.org` and the biblio stuff; create `B.org` that includes `a.org`, `b.org` and the biblio stuff. Export `A.org` and/or `B.org`.

Comment: Yeah... I was hoping to avoid duplication with something like `#+INCLUDE: "a.org" :except "Bibliography"` but I guess some duplication is not the end of the world.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the bibliography link to nobibliography I think.